# Real world use cases where Apache Kafka is used

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted to understand some of the real world use cases where using Apache Kafka as the message broker is most suitable. Considering Kafka topics cannot hold the messages indefinitely.

Comment: Please clarify the needs in this post. An open ended question like this seems like a product critique rather than something to actually answer.

Comment: What i wanted to know was some real world use cases where Kafka is most suitable for. Found Robin answer really useful.

Comment: https://medium.com/@giorgosmyrianthous/why-apache-kafka-d777157ab1e9

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's an example where it's used in retaining the messages indefinitely: https://www.confluent.io/blog/publishing-apache-kafka-new-york-times/

There's use cases for Kafka Streams specifically listed under https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Here's an example of its use in banking: https://www.confluent.io/blog/real-time-financial-alerts-rabobank-apache-kafkas-streams-api/

There's several companies talking about how they use Kafka in the recordings here: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf17/resource/

Answer (score 7):

This is a very broad question with no single correct answer. But: the place I use it most is cases where you need to send a message from a machine to another machine, but don't know which machine exactly.

For example, you're Twitter, and you want to send a new tweet to the browser of everyone following a user. In this case, Users X, Y, and Z (each with their own connection to your servers) are all listening for a message from User Q (on their own connection to your servers). When Q gets a message, it doesn't know where X, Y, and Z are connected exactly, but it knows that perhaps someone would like to know about the message. So, it sends it to the broker, and lets the broker route it to the right places.

Comment: Another thing i wanted to understand was that kafka cannot be used as a persistent storage right ? When a message is sent to the Kafka Broker and all the consumers consume it, that message is going to be deleted from the topic after some point of time.
Is my understand correct ??

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Kafka persists its data regardless of consumer consumption status. You can retain it based on time, on size - or forever (log compaction)